# How can I add a new Page on UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I just created a New Xcode Project as a Page-Based Application and I want to add a new button that will create a new page on runtime. How can I do that?

Actually, an app called "[Dwindle](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dwindle-minimalistic-countdown/id881723551)" has it. It's free to download, just saying it for if someone wants to know what I am talking about.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If that app has that feature, why don't you simply copy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved. The UIPageViewController calculates the number of pages it has, from the delegate method - `presentationCountForPageViewController:`.
You can add a property in your class for example:

```
@property int total;
```

And you can return the property value from the delegate method this way.

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
    return self.total;
}
```

And whenever an event occurs (Ex button click that you mentioned) - you can increment the value for the property - `total` and re-render the pageViewController using the method - `setViewControllers:` .

```
[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This will reload the pageViewController with the new value of `total`.

Comment: Why can you not use the count off of the array viewControllers to know how many pages you have?  Would that not be same?